# How to append new rows into a column of a dataframe based on conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a new category into my existing column based on some conditions

Trial

```
df.loc[df['cat'] == 'woman','age'].max()-df.loc[df['cat'] == 'man','age'].max().apend{'cat': 'first_child', 'age': age}
```

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'cat': ['man1','man', 'woman','woman'], 'age': [30, 40, 50,55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)

cat    age
man    30
man    40
woman  50
woman  55
```

output required:

```
cat         age
man          30
man          40
woman        50
woman        55
first_child  15
sec_child    10
```

Its possible by transpose but actual data is very complex

```
df.transpose()
cat man man woman   woman
age  30  40  50      55
```

---looking for solution in rows amend----

Comment: so you just want to add a new row?
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: Where is "child" coming from? Also "child" isn't a gender...?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to subtract the female age column by the male age column? And append a new row? What should be done when there are more than two rows in your dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I want to add new rows. @Mahrkeenerh

Comment: I changed the col title and added more rows. Actual data is has mulitple unique value and calculation is done in same way.  @ddejohn Please see if you can help.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'cat': ['man1','man2', 'woman1','woman2'], 'age': [30, 40, 50,55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_man = df[df.cat.str.startswith('man')].reset_index(drop=True)
df_woman = df[df.cat.str.startswith('woman')].reset_index(drop=True)

childs = [f'child{i}' for i in range(1, len(df_woman)+1)]
df_child = pd.DataFrame(data={'cat':childs, 'age': (df_woman['age'].sub(df_man['age'])).values})

df = pd.concat([df_man, df_woman, df_child], ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please answer this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69501747/how-to-apply-for-loop-to-append-rows-based-on-multiple-calculation

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the logic behind this but you can use `append`:

```
age = df.loc[df['gender'] == 'female', 'age'].squeeze() \
      - df.loc[df['gender'] == 'male', 'age'].squeeze()

df = df.append({'gender': 'child', 'age': age}, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   gender  age
0    male    3
1  female    4
2   child    1
```