# How to do cumulative division in groupby level [0,1] in pandas dataframe based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, numpy

I have a dataframe where I want append row add some groupby + additional conditions. Looking for for loop or other solution whatever can work.

or if its easier...

`first melt` df and then add `new ratio % col` then `unmelt`.

As calculations are customise, I think `for loop` can find the solution with or without groupby.

---Line 6,7,8 are my requirement.---

`0-14` = `child and unemployed`

`14-50` = `young and working`

`50+` = `old and unemployed`

`# ref line 6,7,8` = `showing which rows to (+) and (/)`

Currently I want to put 3 conditions in output line 6,7,8:

```
d = { 'year': [2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020], 
      'age group': ['(0-14)','(14-50)','(50+)','(0-14)','(14-50)','(50+)'], 
      'con': ['UK','UK','UK','US','US','US'],
      'population': [10,20,300,400,1000,2000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = df.copy()
df

    year    age group   con population
0   2019    (0-14)  UK  10
1   2019    (14-50) UK  20
2   2019    (50+)   UK  300
3   2020    (0-14)  US  400
4   2020    (14-50) US  1000
5   2020    (50+)   US  2000
```

output required:

```
    year    age group           con                   population
0   2019    (0-14)              UK                      10.0
1   2019    (14-50)             UK                      20.0
2   2019    (50+)               UK                      300.0
3   2020    (0-14)              US                      400.0
4   2020    (14-50)             US                      1000.0
5   2020    (50+)               US                      2000.0
6   2019    young vs child      UK-young vs child       2.0   # 20/10
7   2019    old vs young        UK-old vs young          15.0   #300/20
8   2019  unemployed vs working UK-unemployed vs working. 15.5  #300+10 20
```

Trials now:

```
df2 = df.copy()
criteria = [df2['con'].str.contains('0-14'),
            df2['con'].str.contains('14-50'),
            df2['con'].str.contains('50+')]
#conditions should be according to requirements

values = ['young vs child','old vs young', 'unemployed vs working']

df2['con'] = df2['con']+'_'+np.select(criteria, values, 0)
df2['age group'] = df2['age group']+'_'+np.select(criteria, values, 0)

df.groupby(['year','age group','con']).sum().groupby(level=[0,1]).cumdiv()

pd.concat([df,df2])

#----errors. cumdiv() not found and missing conditions criteria-------
```

also tried:

```
df['population'].div(df.groupby('con')['population'].shift(1))

#but looking for customisations into this 
#so it can first sum rows and then divide 
#according to unemployed condition-- row 8 reference.
```

CLOSEST TRAIL

```
n_df_2 = df.copy()
con_list = [x for x in df.con]
year_list = [x for x in df.year]
age_list = [x for x in df['age group']]
new_list = ['young vs child','old vs young', 'unemployed vs working']

for country in con_list:
  

      bev_child =  n_df_2[(n_df_2['con'].str.contains(country)) & (n_df_2['age group'].str.contains(age_list[0]))]
      bev_work =  n_df_2[(n_df_2['con'].str.contains(country)) & (n_df_2['age group'].str.contains(age_list[1]))]
      bev_old =  n_df_2[(n_df_2['con'].str.contains(country)) & (n_df_2['age group'].str.contains(age_list[2]))]


      bev_child.loc[:,'population'] = bev_work.loc[:,'population'].max() / bev_child.loc[:,'population'].max() 
      bev_child.loc[:,'con'] = country +'-'+new_list[0]
      bev_child.loc[:,'age group'] = new_list[0]
      s = n_df_2.append(bev_child, ignore_index=True)


      bev_child.loc[:,'population'] = bev_child.loc[:,'population'].max() + bev_old.loc[:,'population'].max()/ bev_work.loc[:,'population'].max() 
      bev_child.loc[:,'con'] = country +'-'+ new_list[2]
      bev_child.loc[:,'age group'] = new_list[2]

      s = s.append(bev_child, ignore_index=True)

      bev_child.loc[:,'population'] = bev_old.loc[:,'population'].max() / bev_work.loc[:,'population'].max() 
      bev_child.loc[:,'con'] = country +'-'+ new_list[1]
      bev_child.loc[:,'age group'] = new_list[1]

      s = s.append(bev_child, ignore_index=True)
s

year    age group                  con                   population
0   2019    (0-14)                 UK                             10.0
1   2019    (14-50)                UK                             20.0
2   2019    (50+)                  UK                            300.0
3   2020    (0-14)                 US                            400.0
4   2020    (14-50)                US                           1000.0
5   2020    (50+)                  US                           2000.0
6   2020    young vs child         US-young vs child               2.5
7   2020    unemployed vs working  US-unemployed vs working        4.5
8   2020    old vs young           US-old vs young                 2.0
```

also
PLEASE find the easiest way to solve it... Please...

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your question, You want to groupby 1st and 2nd column? where this lines 6,7,8 comes from under `output required`?

Comment: Yes line 6,7,8 are my requirement @haneulkim. That I am showing how it would look like.

Comment: I do not understand what is the new population values. It seems that you are dividing by the previous row but then line 8 makes no sense to me. If you want to divide by the previous value after grouping by "con" then you need this: df['population'].div(df.groupby('con')['population'].shift(1))

Comment: I think groupby will not work in this situation because its a customise division calculation, may be any function can work on it. @tzinie